# Rails 2.3.5 getting a undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running an rails 2.3.5 app and getting a nil:Nilclass in a Controller#show.

This is my Show Action

```
def show
 @category = Category.find_by_url_name(params[:id])
      @brands = @category.brands
      @categories = Category.find(:all)
      @meta_title = "#{@category.name}"

respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
          @brand = @brands.first     
          @search = Product.search.order(params[:order] || 'descend_by_date')

          @products = @search.paginate(:conditions => { :category_id => @category, :brand_id => @brand }, :page => params[:page])      
          render :template => 'brands/show'

  format.xml  { render :xml => @category }
end
end
```

The browser trace info:

```
    /Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in `method_missing'
    /Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/searchlogic-2.5.8/lib/searchlogic/active_record/named_scope_tools.rb:16:in `named_scope_options'
    /Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/searchlogic-     2.5.8/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/alias_scope.rb:54:in `named_scope_options'
    /Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/searchlogic-2.5.8/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/or_conditions.rb:14:in `named_scope_options'
    /Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/searchlogic-2.5.8/lib/searchlogic/search/scopes.rb:15:in `scope_options'
    /Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/searchlogic-2.5.8/lib/searchlogic/search/method_missing.rb:80:in `cast_type'
 /Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/searchlogic-2.5.8/lib/searchlogic/search/method_missing.rb:22:in `method_missing'
/Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/searchlogic-2.5.8/lib/searchlogic/search/method_missing.rb:36:in `send'
/Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/searchlogic-2.5.8/lib/searchlogic/search/method_missing.rb:36:in `method_missing'
/Users/tjs/Sites/emeraldcg/app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:28:in `show'
/Users/tjs/Sites/emeraldcg/app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:25:in `show'
```

It points to the show action line 25 and 28, line 25 is the respond_to do |format|

line 28 is the @search - Product line.

Whats weirder is that if I go to edit the category the url: /categories/amps/edit returns the following:

```
    ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CategoriesController#edit

Couldn't find Category with ID=amps
RAILS_ROOT: /Users/tjs/Sites/emeraldcg

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
/Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1586:in `find_one'
/Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1569:in `find_from_ids'
/Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:616:in `find'
/Users/tjs/Sites/emeraldcg/app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:50:in `edit'
```

my Category model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brands, :through => :products, :uniq => true
  has_many :products
 # acts_as_friendly_param :name

 validates_presence_of :url_name
 validates_uniqueness_of :url_name

 def to_param
  self.url_name
 end
end
```

This app worked fine before rails 3... so frustrating, I am a newer Rails dev so still trying to figure out how to go back and use rails 2 projects.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can always replace `@category = Category.find_by_url_name(params[:id])` with `@category = Category.find(:first, :conditions => ["url_name = ?", params[:id]])`.

Switching to Rails 3.1 will be even better ;)

Answer (score 0):

"Couldn't find Category with ID=amps" is a result of the the query which tries to find a record using id.
eg:

```
User.find('amps')
will be converted into 
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='amps';
```

Please make sure you are using the right code to find category.

Comment: Users aren't involved...  @category = Category.find_by_url_name(params[:id]) is finding categories by url_name which is a methods
validates_presence_of :url_name
 validates_uniqueness_of :url_name
 
 def to_param
  self.url_name
 end

Comment: Well i have specified User as an example here. By rails convention, restful resource /categories/amps/edit is mapped to /categories/:id/edit. So i suspect either you are using Category.find(params[:id]) in the edit action or somewhere.

Comment: Oh ok I think I get what you are saying... Sorry for the users confusion. My categories table has a url_name field which allows the admin to create a cleaner url structure, which is where the def to_param self.url_name end method comes into play and the @category instance variable is pulling from url_name as well... thanks for the help.  I don't totally get it yet but you guys are pointing me in the right dir.

Answer (score 0):

As @nkm pointed out, this error happens when your app is trying to search category from an id called 'amps'

Check your show url and check your routes.rb file to see if Category has configured as Resource

HTH

sameera